# how I can install Kubernetes on Linux

Tags: system-installation

I used AWS cloud to start to learn how to install docker and play with commands. Now I need your help to install Kubernetes on Linux
which command can I use?
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: A must read to help you get started is https://kubernetes.io/

Answer (score 0):

MicroK8s is a lightweight, zero-ops Kubernetes for Linux, Windows and macOS. A single command installs all upstream Kubernetes services and their dependencies. With support for x86 and ARM64, MicroK8s runs from local workstations to the edge and IoT appliances.

1. Install MicroK8s.

   ```
   sudo snap install microk8s --classic
   ```
2. Check the status while Kubernetes starts.

   ```
   microk8s status --wait-ready
   ```
3. Turn on the services you want.

   ```
   microk8s enable dashboard dns registry istio
   ```

   Try `microk8s enable --help` for a list of available services and optional features. `microk8s disable <name>` turns off a service.
4. Start using Kubernetes

   ```
   microk8s kubectl get all --all-namespaces
   ```

   If you mainly use MicroK8s you can make our kubectl the default one on your command-line with `alias mkctl="microk8s kubectl"`. Since it is a standard upstream kubectl, you can also drive other Kubernetes clusters with it by pointing to the respective kubeconfig file via the `--kubeconfig` argument.
5. Access the Kubernetes dashboard.

   ```
   microk8s dashboard-proxy
   ```
6. Start and stop Kubernetes to save battery.

   Kubernetes is a collection of system services that talk to each other all the time. If you don’t need them running in the background then you will save battery by stopping them. `microk8s start` and `microk8s stop` will do the work for you.

<sub>**Source:** [Install Kubernetes | Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/kubernetes/install)</sub>